# Zorn's Lemma and Zermelo's Theorem ( James Dugundji Page - 31)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Theorem : The following three Statements are equivalent

(1) The axiom of choice

(2) Let $X$ be an preordered set . If a chain in $X$ has an upper bound, then $X$ has atleast one maximal element .

(3) Every set can be well ordered set.

I have doubt in this part $(2) \Rightarrow (3)$

Let $ X$ be a preordered set with relation $\prec$. Let $\mathscr{F}$ be the family of all ordered couples $\{ (A,\prec_A)|  ( A \subset E) \wedge ( \prec_A$ is a well ordering of $A)\}$

What is the relation $\prec_A$ on $A$

Comment: You are asking what the relation $\prec_A$ is? Why don't you start by asking what the set $A$ is?

Answer (score 1):

The definition of $\prec_A$ is written right there in the definition of $\scr F$. $A$ is a subset of $E$, and $\prec_A$ is a well-ordering of $A$.

For example, if $A=\{x,y\}$, then $\prec_A$ could be $\{(x,y)\}$ in which case $x\prec_A y$, or it could be $\{(y,x)\}$ in which case $y\prec_A x$ (but of course not both).

Which one specifically? You take *all* possible well-orderings of $A$, and all possible subsets of $E$ with this property. There are no additional restrictions here.